# Is there any unique value for Euler Phi Function $\phi(n)$?

Tags: totient-function

I know $\phi(n) = \phi(2n)$ for $n$ odd and greater than $1$. I wonder if there any value $k$ such that $\phi(n) = k$ for a unique $n$. $\phi(2) = \phi(1) = 1$ so of course $1$ cannot be that value. I know $n$ must be even.

I have looked at a few pages like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/generalizing-values-which-eulers-totient-function-does-not-take) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291334/values-taken-by-eulers-phi-function), but I am not sure if this question has been addressed. If there is any unique value of $\phi(n)$, then would there be infinitely many of them or only finitely many.

Comment: Previous discussions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971626/what-is-the-state-of-carmichaels-totient-function-conjecture also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181627/solutions-of-phix-n-for-a-given-n

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have rediscovered [Carmichael's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function_conjecture): we believe that there is no such $k$, but it is still an open problem.

Comment: Carmichael proposed this as an exercise in his 1914 intro Number Theory textbook.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Does that mean he knew the proof?

Comment: @Asher, it means he *thought* he knew a proof. He was wrong. See also the link Greg provided.

Comment: The article mentions the incredible lower bound for a possible solution : It is $10^{10^{10}}$ (!!)

Comment: @Peter: Was that lower bound obtained via analytical methods?